# Function is not correctly incrementing variable by 1

Tags: c, while-loop, fopen, do-while, eof

I have a function that returns the number of lines, characters, and words in an array. For some reason, when i loop through the array to print the values I am only getting the corrrect value for lines, the characters and words are returning as 0. All the functions are predetermined by my professor and my job is to fill them in.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int *myArray = get_counts(argv[1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
                printf("%d\n", myArray[i]);
        }
        return 0;
}
int *get_counts(char *filename)
{
        FILE *file;

        file = fopen(filename, "r");

        if (file == NULL)
        {
                printf("NULL FILE");
        }

        char c;
        int h;
        bool whitespace = true;
        static int arr[3] = {0,0,0};

        do
        {
                c = fgetc(file);
                if (c == '\n')
                {
                        arr[0] ++;
                }
        }while (c != EOF);

        while (true)
        {
                h = fgetc(file);

                if (feof(file))
                {
                        break;
                }
                else if (ferror(file))
                {
                        printf("error reading file");
                }
                arr[2] ++;

                if (whitespace && !isspace(h))
                {
                        arr[1] ++;
                        whitespace = false;
                }
                else if (!whitespace &&isspace(h))
                {
                        whitespace = true;
                }
        }
        fclose(file);
        return arr;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code to help figure out where your logic error is located and what's going wrong. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to start learning. A debugger is the most powerful tool a programmer has available to them, and it's never too early to start using one.

Comment: @Jason Fan After the first do-while loop the EOF condition occurs.

Comment: You need to do something other than continue as usual if fopen fails.

Comment: Using `char` variable (such as `c`) to hold the return value of `fgetc` is dangerous, as it can't hold all possible return values (EOF(-1) or 0..255).  At best if your file contains a 0xff character, it will be seen as a premature EOF.  At worst (on a system where `char` is unsigned) it will never terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option is probably to just iterate through the file in one loop (you could also `rewind()` after the first loop).  Use the return value of `fgetc()` to determine of you are at `EOF` instead of separate `feof()` calls.  I also made the the result array an (out) argument instead of using a static variable (the latter is not reentrant if you ever want to call this from multiple threads and it's easy to do):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void get_counts(char *filename, int arr[3]) {
    memset(arr, 0, 3 * sizeof(int));
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("NULL FILE");
        return;
    }
    bool whitespace = true;
    for(;;) {
        int c = fgetc(file);
        if(c == EOF)
            break;
        else if(c == '\n')
            arr[0]++;
        else if (whitespace && !isspace(c)) {
            arr[1]++;
            whitespace = false;
        } else if (!whitespace && isspace(c))
            whitespace = true;
        arr[2]++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int myArray[3];
    get_counts(argv[1], myArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

The output on the above file is:

```
39
94
715
```

The word count 94 doesn't agree with `wc -w` but you could be using a different definition of what a word is.

It's a good idea to separate calculations and i/o, so consider opening and closing the file in `main()` and pass in the file handle.  It becomes easy, for instance, to use the `stdin` file handle instead if you don't want to use a physical file.

Answer (score 0):

After the first do-while loop the condition EOF occurs.

```
    do
    {
            c = fgetc(file);
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                    arr[0] ++;
            }
    }while (c != EOF);
```

So the following while loop has no effect.

You should use only one loop to count lines, words and characters.

Pay attention to that the variable `c` should be declared as having the type `int`

```
int c;
```

Also you need to exit the function if the file was not opened.